# How to trigger an event using state_machine gem in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine

I'm looking to use the state_machine gem for a project but I'm stuck on how to call an event in a Rails 3.1 application.

I understand how to set up the state_machine, as below:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  state_machine :initial => :parked do
    event :ignite do
      transition :parked => :idling
    end
  end
end
```

And I understand, that this gives me the following options:

```
vehicle = Vehicle.create    # => #<Vehicle id=1 state="parked">
vehicle.ignite              # => true
vehicle.state
```

But how would I change the state of the Vehicle in a Rails application?  Does vehicle.ignite get called from a controller?  or is it in before_save method? Do I have a button on a page with an AJAX call to a special route to ignite engine?

How does the app know to call the ignite method?  Do I have to pass some type of flag to check if I should ignite in a POST (ie, attr_accessor :mark_as_ignited or based on other variables it knows to call the ignite method?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You transition from one state to another by calling that event name with a !

```
vehicle.ignite!
```

As for how you would know when to call it, you would setup a route possibly in the controller. This could be something as simple as the following.

```
def ignite
  @vehicle = Vehicle.find params[:id]
  @vehicle.ignite!
  render :show
end
```

You'd have to setup the necessary member endpoint in your routes file and put the appropriate link wherever you feel necessary but that's it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Thats what I was thinking.  Would you recommend having 1 separate route for each event or would you have one route called "update_status" and then just pass a parameter to trigger which event to call?

Comment: I would tend to follow SRP (single responsibility principle) and not have them all in one.

Comment: You can also use `@vehicle.fire_state_event(:ignite)` if that makes more sense with your code.